# How do I catch Exception in SML from another function?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I believe I have some basic misunderstanding about catching exceptions in SML.

I wrote the following code:

```
    fun my_g acc p =
    let 
    val r =  my_g acc
    in
    case p of
        Wildcard          => acc 
      | Variable x        =>    if List.exists (fn y => y = x) acc then raise NoAnswer else x::acc 
      | TupleP ps         => List.foldl (fn (p,i) => (my_g i p)) acc  ps
      | ConstructorP(_,p) => r p
      | _                 => acc
    end

(* val check_pat = fn : pattern -> bool *)          
 fun check_pat p =
   if my_g []  p <> [] then
            true
else
    true      
 handle NoAnswer => false
```

I'm happy to explain the code in gory detail, but basically I'm looking to see if strings are repeated in a list.  If I find a string repeated, I raise an exception.  Notice I'm handling the exception in function check_pat, which calls function my_g.  However, when I run the code with some test methods, I get uncaught exception NoAnswer

Can I catch an exception thrown in one function in another (calling) function?
What am I doing wrong?

### Thanks, Dave

Additional details for Andreas and future viewers.  The original hints were to first unfold  the structure and get a list of strings and only then go through and look for duplicates.  I felt that was inefficient and it would be best to look for duplicates as you unfolded.  Unfortunately, my SML knowledge is not good enough to come up with a super clean solution.  Really, I don't care about the return value of my_g.  If it doesn't throw an exception, then there are no duplicates.  As simple as that.  But it seemed the syntax rules were forcing me to check the return value.  Now that you've solved the "handle" issue for me, I might revisit the problem.  I was hoping to just write:

```
(my_g [] p
true)
handle NoAnswer => false
```

but that didn't seem to work.  More broadly, although I think my solution is more efficient than first unfolding the entire list just to then look for duplicates, I suspect the idea of using an exception like I did is not good style.  In languages I'm familiar with (C++, C#), an exception means some exceptional or unexpected occurred.  Finding a duplicate string is certainly not exceptional.  Again, I'm sure there is another way to stop at the first duplicate without using exceptions.  I'm just not proficient enough in SML to know it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you declare the constructor for your exception?

Comment: Marco,  Yes I did.  I forgot to put it in the question.  Sorry about that.  It is:  exception NoAnswer    Also, see answer by Andreas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is simply a matter of parenthesization: `handle` binds tighter than `if`, so you have effectively written

```
if ... then ... else (... handle ...)
```

Instead you want

```
(if ... then ... else ...) handle ...
```

so you need to put in parentheses.

BTW, I can't make sense of your use of `if` -- why a conditional when both branches produce the same result? Also, `if A then true else B` is a verbose way of saying `A orelse B`.

*Edit* in reply to edit in the question: If you want to ignore the result of an expression and return something else instead then you can use the semicolon operator:

```
(my_g [] p; true)
```

However, in general, using exceptions for non-exceptional control flow is not recommended. There is a cleaner way to write this function:

```
fun ids (Variable x)       = [x]
  | ids (Tuple ps)         = List.concat (List.map ids ps)
  | ids (Constructor(_,p)) = ids p
  | ids _                  = []

fun hasDups []      = false
  | hasDups (x::xs) = List.exists (fn y => y = x) xs orelse hasDups xs

fun checkPat p = not (hasDups (ids p))
```

Edit 2: In the normal case (where there are no duplicates), this solution isn't slower than the other. So it's not necessarily worth taking the shortcut. If you insist, though, there are various options that don't require exceptions. For example:

```
fun checkPat'(_, NONE)               = NONE
  | checkPat'(Variable x, SOME xs)   = if List.exists (fn y => y = x) xs then NONE else SOME (x::xs)
  | checkPat'(Tuple ps, xso)         = List.foldl checkPat' xso ps
  | checkPat'(Constructor(_,p), xso) = checkPat'(p, xso)
  | checkPat'(_, xso)                = xso

fun checkPat p = isSome (checkPat'(p, SOME []))
```

Or, if you are willing to use a bit of mutable state:

```
fun checkPat' xs (Variable x)       = List.exists (fn y => y = x) (!xs) before (xs := x :: !xs)
  | checkPat' xs (Tuple ps)         = List.all (checkPat' xs) ps
  | checkPat' xs (Constructor(_,p)) = checkPat' xs p
  | checkPat' xs _                  = true

fun checkPat p = checkPat' (ref []) p
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas!  I'm new to SML and am having a hard time with the syntax.  I was well aware of "both branches produce the same result" and have given an explanation as an edit to the question (I needed to put code in and others might be interested).  Believe me, I feel sheepish about that one, but couldn't figure out the correct way :)  Thanks again!

Comment: @Dave, and one more edit showing alternative solutions :)

Comment: Thanks Andreas.  The ";" was something I hadn't tried, although I should have given they are ubiquitous in C#/C++! I like your middle example very much.  As for the "normal" case, I'd fully expect that if you gave me a list of 10000 items, there would be duplicates even if you swore there were not.  Besides, I'm still proud of myself for considering the possibility of not going through the whole list with fold or map before checking for duplicates :)

Comment: Seriously, it did occur to me that perhaps the act of using fold (or map) is inconsequential time-wise in comparison to List.exits. If so, that would be a good reason to favor your first example.  Thanks again!